# Load specific div of addressValue jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, load

I am having this function:

```
    $(".products li a").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $( "#stap_2" ).addClass("stap_2_tonen");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#stap_2").offset().top
                }, 1000);

                $("#loader_tickets").addClass( "toon_loader" );     
                var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");        
                $("#bestellen").load(addressValue); 
});
```

It works okay but now I need to hide elements from the addressValue with CSS but I want to load a specific div of that addressValue.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: provide an example of `addressValue`

Comment: /product/2-uur-skipas-kinderen/

So normally it would work like: $("#bestellen").load("/product/2-uur-skipas-kinderen/ .single-product-summary"); 

But because I am putting it in a variable it doesn't work when I write it like this: 
$("#bestellen").load(addressValue .single-product-summary);